# Changing the footer in magento theme

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, ce-1.9.0.1, footer

I'm fairly new to editing the footer in magento. I want to transform footer. I managed to change only address part, but not the rest. Getting struck in complex file structure of Magento.

I want to transform this footer:

[image: old one]

into this one:

[image: new one]

Please help me out.

Comment: @Marius: any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`, do a find for "footer" and you'll get right to the Footer blocks.  The "Quick Links" are actually set under various spots in `System > Configuration`.

Here's what I'd suggest:

Make `local.xml` (in the same folder as `page.xml` above) if you haven't yet, and remove the "Quick Links" and "My Account" blocks if you don't plan to use them.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <remove name="footer_links"/>
            <remove name="footer_links2"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Now you can make two static CMS blocks for the two other sections you want, and add them in via `local.xml` again.  Say you call them `footer_posts` and `footer_news`, we're adding more into `local.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <remove name="footer_links"/>
            <remove name="footer_links2"/>
            <block type="cms/block" name="footer_posts">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_posts</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <block type="cms/block" name="footer_news">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_news</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Tested on a fresh 1.9 install and it works just fine.

Comment: I did as you told, however I got 2 footers where quick links and account were removed... I added new footer blocks to footer.phtml and nothing appeared. Is it possible to add a image in comments? If so, then please enlighten me

Comment: I just fixed it, now I'm getting only one footer, however Posts and News aren't appearing in footer

Comment: Actually it looks like editing the `footer.phtml` file isn't even necessary, I have the blocks showing up a fresh Magento install by just making the CMS blocks then `local.xml` as above.  Make sure your Block IDs when you make them in CMS match up with the IDs set in `local.xml`.  Also, have you refreshed (or I'd recommend disabling it until you're ready to go live) your cache after these changes?

Comment: Speaking of cache though, that's the one "gotcha" with this.  The footer in Magento is always cached, and it looks like you want dynamic content in it.  You're likely going to have to override it and remove the caching.  Marius has a post about it here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/different-footer-per-page

Comment: I removed footer block cache by using this link
http://ken.edmonds-commerce.co.uk/magento/disable-footer-block-caching-in-magento/
So adding blocks to footer should be easy now

Answer (score -5):

[image: Try this !]

TO remove newsletter block from the footer for the Magento 1.9. ---> try this !

Comment: Although it would remove it from the footer probably it would also remove it from a ton of other locations. It's bit too drastic for what OP is asking in my opinion