# How to only show cms block in phtml file on homepage

Tags: php, custom, programming

we need to show cms block in footer of homepage only

our block is called footer_partners

We tried both

```
<?php $ref = new Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header(); if($ref->getIsHomePage()): ?>
<div class="grid_12">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shopper_footer_partners'); ?>
</div>
```

and

```
<?php if($route == 'cms' && $action == 'index'): ?>
<div class="grid_12">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shopper_footer_partners'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But both methods seem to work fine - but then I saw it underneath the cart and also underneath the login

Question: Now how could I do this correctly using phtml?

Question: Is there a way to access my custom coded phtml block using XML? (and this way show it only, only on the homepage)

thx

Comment: see this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2721/146

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to homepage > Design > Layout Custom XML and paste this:

```
<reference name="footer">
<block type="cms/block" name="footer-partners">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_partners</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: it's supposed to display on cms_index_index only, check if this block was set in page.xml or catalog.xml,etc , and may have to recache