# Extended footer for HOMEPAGE and normal footer for Other pages

Tags: magento-1.9, footer

In my Current Project there is requirement like this Extended footer for HOMEPAGE and normal footer for Other pages how can I get this.

Comment: Check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/2719/146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually this is easily solvable just by one line

put this code in your footer.phtml file above your footer div `<div class="footer"`>

```
<?php $is_homepage = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage();  ?>
<?php if($is_homepage): ?>
<!-- Homepage footer contents here -->
```

and end this after your footer div

```
<?php else: ?>

<!--
put your other pages footer contents here.....
-->



<?php endif; ?>
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: man thankyou this think worked for me.

Comment: This won't work with the block cache on. Depending on what page you visit first you will see your code that should be on homepage on all pages or you won't even see it in the homepage

Comment: but it is working for me dude.