# How to comment new CMS block on the page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cms

I was building my website and I am facing an issue there.

I created CMS block for the page and added this in the upper section of my page.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_block') ?>
```

I put reference name in to `local.xml` like this.

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="footer-company" as="footer-company">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer-company</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

and this seems to be not working at all. I also tried to add this manually for home page under `Design` tab and I got an error for that.

So my question is, Is there any other way to put this CMS block on my page?
I think that `local.xml` doesn't work any more with Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is `local.xml` will work in Magento 1.9. There is no doubt in that.

The problem here is, you are trying to add your cms block inside `footer` block and `footer` block is a core block which will be cached "always" by Magento for better page load performance. Since Magento uses cache for rendering footer section, new changes that you have made in footer section via layout update is not going to work.

***[Have a look on this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/different-footer-per-page)***. You will get a clear idea. If you have any further doubts, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes. I created a file with layout.xml and commented it as local.xml. As I see it doesn't work at all. I am gonna try to get file names as local.xml