# Inserted code in footer and product dissappere

Tags: html, footer, code

I have a problem with some code deleting itself.
I have inserted an image in the footer, just below the newsletter subscribe button, and a code showing the stock lvl on the product pages.
But after a while, its gone. And when I look at the code, its deleted.

Anyone know why and how to fix it?

**Footer code:**

```
<br> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/betaling6.png') ?>" alt="betaling" />*
```

**Product page code:** Can't show whole code here, but I found it here:
http://www.toweringmedia.com/blog/?p=21

Comment: Do you have some kind of footer extension that possibly re- and overwrites your footer?

Comment: can you provide the code you used?

Comment: Might be non standard (Magento acceptable) html that saves on first save but on re open is filtered out. We have had that issue before

Comment: @Aardi No, it also happens to a vode I use to show the stock lvl on products

Comment: @Marius Sure, the first is with the image: 
<br>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/betaling6.png') ?>" alt="betaling" />
The second is to show stock lvl on products:
Too long to post, butI got it from here: http://www.toweringmedia.com/blog/?p=21

Comment: @snh_nl So is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the footer is cached.
Since you want that image on certain on certain pages, maybe you first hit a page that should not have the image, the footer gets cached and it is never rebuild to include your image.
You can find a solution for this problem in this SE answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2721/146

Comment: Hmm okay, I checked out the thread, but I'm not sure I understand it. Can you specify it and maybe include my code?