# Block visibility random, cache issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, ce-1.9.2.4

I have two simple cms blocks added into theme layout file (local.xml) under `<default>`:

```
<reference name="footer">
            <block type="cms/block" name="footer_leather_catalogo">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_leather_catalogo</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <block type="cms/block" name="footer_leather_catalogo_2">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_leather_catalogo_2</block_id></action>
            </block>
</reference>
```

In addition I remove them in two pages: the HP and a custom page of my module:

```
<reference name="footer">
<remove name="footer_leather_catalogo" />
<remove name="footer_leather_catalogo_2" />
</reference>
```

In HP, to show the blocks in the right place, after removed them, I add them again:

```
<div class="inner-container">
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="66"}}
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="67"}}
</div>
```

All works fine but if I apply some catalog rules (or any other actions that needs clear the cache) and flush Magento cache, I see the blocks into custom pages and twice into HP.
If I flush Magento cache again, two or three times, they disappear, and again.. flush Magento cache, they are shown in custom page and HP (twice)..

I don't understand how to solve this tedious issue.

Comment: take a look at the answers here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/2719/146

Comment: Thank you Marius, you're right but I thought to create a block (not in footer block, a root child) to solve my issue.